# EF connectionstring for AspNetIdentity table causing errors when placed in main projects webconfig

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

I am running into a problem with an EF connectionstring in my main project's webconfig. The Ef connectionstring is for Identity tables, if I log in and have the EF connectionstring in my main project's webconfig,

```
<add name="HWCIdentityEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HWCIdentityEF.csdl|res://*/HWCIdentityEF.ssdl|res://*/HWCIdentityEF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****;initial catalog=*****;persist security info=True;user id=*****;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I get an error

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

and its pointing at

```
Line 78: var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false); in my AccountController
```

However, If I use this version of the connectionstring in my main project's webconfig

```
<add name="HWCIdentityEntities" connectionString="Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=****;password=****;Integrated Security=false;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Then I can login no problems.

I can't use the 2nd option for my connectionstring because I am running an ajax call to get query the AspNetUsers table to get the logged in user's id and placing that in a javascript variable so I can access it throughout the application.

This is how I am running the ajax in _LoginPartial

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        CommonMethod.GetCurrentUserID($('#loggedInUser').text().replace("Hello ", "").replace("!", ""));
    });
</script>
```

and the GetCurrentUserID call is

```
GetCurrentUserID: function (useremail) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../CommonMethods/GetCustomerID?useremail=" + useremail,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            HWCStorage.Keys.CurrentUserID = data;
        }
    });
}
```

and that calls

```
[HttpGet]
    public string GetCustomerID(string useremail)
    {
        HDA = new HWCDA();
        return HDA.CurrentUserID(useremail);
    }
```

and that calls this

```
public string CurrentUserID(string useremail)
    {
        string userID = string.Empty;

        HWCI = new HWCIdentityEntities();

        userID = HWCI.AspNetUsers.Where(w => w.Email == useremail).Select(s=>s.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        return userID;
    }
```

So in short I need to know why I can't use the EF connectionstring for the Identities in my main projects web config

Comment: I fail to see how an ajax call can dictate the shape of a connection string.

Comment: @GertArnold, you are right it doesn't dictate anything, i was showing what I am trying to do, but I can't do it without the EF connectionstring